# ¿en qué línea se detectó un error de sintaxis? y ¿cuál es el error?

Tags: c++, arduino

[image: consulta de errores]

¿en qué línea se detectó un error de sintaxis? y ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: buenas noches su ayuda por favor

Comment: quieres que alguien resuelva el ejercicio que te pasaron?? ;)

Comment: estoy estudiando, todavia no tengo mucho conocimiento en esto. una ayudita estaria mal. jejej

Comment: una ayuda? o una resolucion? una ayuda seria decirte, lee linea por linea, y analiza si la linea funciona en un compilador...

Comment: Hola Sneider, bienvenido, empecemos por el principio, si quieres ayuda, edita tu pregunta, borra la imagen, y agrega tu código como texto, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!. la cantidad de errores es importante....

Comment: ayudita a la solucion jejeje

Comment: me falta mucho por aprender

Comment: *¿En qué línea se detectó un error de sintaxis?* -> Pues, con la poca información que nos das, imposible decirte. Entendemos que te falta mucho por aprender, pero vamos, nos es difícil leer línea por línea e identificar en qué fallaste, incluso, el IDE que usas debe marcarte el error de sintaxis... como muchos dicen: *la mejor forma de aprender es intentándolo* :)...

Comment: borra la imagen, agregá texto...

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Actualmente, tu pregunta no cumple con los lineamientos de la comunidad, te invito a realizar el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a incluir un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en tu pregunta, de esta manera podremos entender mejor tu problema y ayudarte a buscar soluciones potenciales, ya que actualmente tu pregunta no se entiende.

Comment: En la linea 8, tienes un `:` en vez de una `,`.

Answer (score 1):

No te voy a dar las respuestas, porque creo que te va a servir responderlas, pero te voy a ayudar...

**Declarar variables**:
**Enteros**:

```
   // con "int" le digo que es un entero, luego va el nombre que le quiero dar,  
   // con "=" le asigno el valor que está a la derecha  
   // solo admite números enteros  
int nombreDeLaVariable = 12;
```

**Decimales**:

```
   // con "double" le digo que es decimal, acepta enteros y decimales  
double nombreDeLaVariable = 1.2;
```

**Cadenas**:

```
  // con "String" le indico que es cadena, para asignar, pongo el texto entre comillas  
  // solo acepta texto  
String nombreDeLaVariable = "texto de prueba";
```

nota: una variable se puede declarar sin asignarle ningún valor, ej: **int valor;**.
nota: todos las declaraciones de variables, terminan el "**;**".
nota: las variables las puedo declarar en un lugar del código, y asignarle un valor en otro, pero siempre las debo declarar.

**Palabras reservadas**:

Son palabras que usa el sistema, y que no pueden ser usadas como nombres de variables o métodos, va una lista (incompleta):

```
int, double, String, for, while, if, else if, else, void...
```

**Métodos**:
**Declarar un método**:

primero se pone el tipo de objeto que se devuelve ...ej: **int**, **String**, etc.
luego el nombre del método.
después y entre paréntesis, los parámetros que recibe separados por comas... ej: **( int cantidad )**.
finalmente va "**{**" seguida del contenido del método y "**}**".

```
void calcularLaNotaQueMeSaco( int cantidadDeErroresEncontrados ) {
    int nota = 0;
    if( cantidadDeErroresEncontrados == 9 ) {
        nota = 10;
    }
}
```

nota: la palabra reservada **void**, indica que el método no devuelve nada.
nota: si un método no recibe parámetros se colocan los paréntesis vacíos **int calcular() {**.
nota: como se ve, los parámetros deben estar precedidos de su tipo.

**Llamar a un método**:

Para llamar a un método colocamos el nombre seguido de los paréntesis entre los cuales van los nombres de los parámetros.

```
int errores = 7;
calcularLaNotaQueMeSaco( errores );
```

ejemplo de método que recibe varios parámetros:

```
int calcular( String texto, String letra ) {

       // el método **cuantasHay** devuelve algo, entonces lo guardo en una variable
    int resultado = cuantasHay( texto, letra );  
}
```

nota: en las llamadas a métodos, los parámetros pueden ser pasados como variables, o como literal, ej: **int resultado = calcular( 23 );**
nota: todos los llamados a métodos, terminan el "**;**".

**Comparaciones**:

Solo se pueden comparar objetos del mismo tipo, por ejemplo **double** con **double**, **int** con **int**, sino se produce un error:

```
int cantos = 5;
int feos = 4;
if( cantos == feos ) {
    System.out.println( "tamoalorno" );
}
```

si en cambio quiero hacer

```
if( 3 == "colores" ) {
```

me va a arrojar un error.

Bueno, creo que tienes lo necesario para empezar, no está todo, no todo lo que digo es estricto, pero te va a servir para encontrar los errores.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que `String` es una palabra reservada? ¿Por qué consideras `else if` una sola palabra? Dejo un enlace a la [lista exhaustiva de palabras reservadas en C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Comment: @JorgeLuis, hola, cuando la respondí, una de las etiquetas era "java", (otra era C#) como me pareció que el código era muy "java" conteste en consecuencia... bien por estar atento.